# How to pull in route parameters in class components within React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, routes, state

I'm working on an old React Native app and am not familiar with class based components, I have a boolean value (isJobOwner) which I want to pass from one screen to the other, and then on that next screen check whether the isJobOwner boolean is true or false, in which case I will take the user onto a final screen dependent on the truthy or falsy value of that using a ternary operator.

My 2 files currently look like this:

SignUpChoice.js:

```
class SignUpChoice extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: (
            <Header
                leftComponent={<GoBackComponent onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />}
                containerStyle={commonStyles.headerContainer}
                centerComponent={<CustomHeader name="Account Type" />}
            />
        ),
    });

    onChooseRole(isJobOwner) {
        saveRole(isJobOwner ? 'owner' : 'seeker');
        NavigationService.navigate('Tutorial', { isJobOwner: isJobOwner });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <View style={styles.signUpChoiceContainer}>
                        <Button
                            style={styles.jobButton}
                            onPress={() => this.onChooseRole(true)}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.jobText}>
                                Are you looking for a Tradesman?
                            </Text>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            style={styles.jobButton}
                            onPress={() => this.onChooseRole(false)}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.jobText}>Are you looking for work?</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Tutorial.js:

```
class Tutorial extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = { header: null };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }

    onNextStep() {
        // NavigationService.navigate(isJobOwner ? 'FindEmployers' : 'FindJobs');
        this.props.navigation.navigate(
            this.props.isJobOwner ? 'FindEmployers' : 'FindJobs'
        );
    }

    onGoBack() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpChoice');
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Container>
                {(this.props.requesting || this.state.isLoading) && (
                    <Loader size={'large'} color={colors.white} />
                )}
                <Content contentContainerStyle={{ height: '100%' }}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                        <Button
                            transparent
                            style={styles.tutorialButton}
                            onPress={() => this.onNextStep()}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.tutorialButtonText}>Next Step</Text>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            transparent
                            style={styles.backButton}
                            onPress={() => this.onGoBack()}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>Go Back</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

When onNextStep is clicked, I want to navigate to either the FindEmployers or FindJobs screen dependent on if isJobOwner is true or false.

I know this is pretty simple but any quick advice would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) you can:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Tutorial', { isJobOwner: isJobOwner });
```

And then retrieve the route params with:

```js
class Tutorial extends React.Component {
  render() {
     const { navigation } = this.props;    
     const isJobOwner = navigation.getParam('isJobOwner', false);
     ...
  }
}
```

Check the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/params for more

Comment: Hi, yes it's using React Navigation 3 so everythings a little outdated but thanks, that seems to have worked well and exactly what i needed, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

```
this.props.isJobOwner
```

This is correct code.

```
this.props.route.params.isJobOwner
```

Please test using `console.info(this.props.route.params)`

In summary,

First screen : `this.props.navigation.navigate('Tutorial', { isJobOwner: isJobOwner })`

Second screen : `console.info(this.props.route.params.isJobOwner`